# WebBrowser Flicker in selenium webdriver

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, build-automation

I am using selenium webdriver and running it on  IE10 .The webbrowser Flickers and the test fail and solution for this issue.It works fine in Firefox

Actually the web page flickers and all the other test case fails saying "Element is not displayed"

Comment: Can you post the error message when the test fails?

Comment: Actually the web page flickers and all the other test case fails saying "Element is not displayed".

Comment: the browsers moves and the click on the elements fails.I am using IE9

Comment: Can you try using IE8, let us see what happens?

Comment: Tried with IE8 it happens the same .But when it is run with FireFox it works fine

Comment: I tried minimizing the Browser Window and ran,If I do so It work fine and it does not flickers.But if i Minimise and run the testcase then the screenshot for failed testcase is not captured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happens to me as well in IE 6 & 8 browsers. The window just maximizes and minimizes itself randomly failing all the tests. No relevant stacktrace in the logs either. Anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Once the browser opens, try to minimize the minimize.Check whether it fails.I tried in this method and it didn't flicker.Just give a try

Comment: Sorry, I've had a nightmare fighting my internet for the past 2 days. I tried minimizing the IE window after it opened, the tests seemed to carry on but each one of them failed since it was unable to find the element for keying in inputs. When I brought the window back to normal position, it started flickering again and the tests failed and just ended. Just can't understand what causes this, any clues?

Comment: In my case, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14019225/934307) automatically fixed this for me.

Comment: how can we "minimize" browser in automation(I am using protractor), I could not find any command to minimize. @Pat your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have this same problem of Flickering while taking the screenshot in IE, i have searched all over the internet and found no solution for this issue.

I have found this alternate solution for taking the screenshots for the test steps.

I have not used the webdriver API to take the screenshot but instead relied on Java Robot API to take the screenshot.

use the following code for taking the screenshots in IE without any flickering.

```
public static boolean TakeScreenshot(String filePath){
    boolean b = false;
    try {
        BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));

        b = ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(filePath));            

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return b;
}
```

Let me know if this solution works for you....

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the framework logs screenshot after each step. if you remove screenshot method for IE. Then it will not flicker .. Give a try..

Comment: Not an answer, this is a comment.