# Selenium Webdriver can't find elements on IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here's a strange issue I'm facing right now.

The Firefox driver locates an element in my webpage however my IE driver doesn't. I thought it would be down to browsers handling the xpaths differently, but that doesn't seem to be my problem: trying to find elements by id, name and everything else fails with the IE driver.

This lead me to believe that the html might not have been a properly constructed one. I was wrong again, it was very well constructed and if I saved the webpage as html and tried with selenium's By id or By name on the saved html file, it worked!

It just won't work on my webpage. FYI, it's SSL enabled. I just can't believe that could be causing issues cos it finds elements on https://www.google.com with ease. Anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: is the element being dynamically constructed/updated with javascript after pageload?

Comment: No it's not. It's available on pageload. And FWIW, the IE driver doesn't find ANY element on that webpage.

Comment: which client libraries for selenium are you using?

Comment: I'm using selenium-java:2.25.0.

Comment: Could you plz show the html code and the code that you are trying?

Comment: the html would be helpful as well as webdriver api call that throws noSuchElementException.

Comment: Is there any chance that you're setting the capability for ignoring the Protected Mode settings of IE? In Java, it's called `INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS`, and has other similar names in other language bindings. Ignoring Protected Mode settings can lead to [unpredictable results](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html).

Comment: I tried setting that to false myself. No effect :( It's set to false by default.

Abhi_Mishra, @frennky I'd try posting a similar html shortly.

Comment: See my comments on one of the answers on how I got around the issue. Anyhow, my sincere thanks to you frennky and Abhi_Mishra for looking into this. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be the elements are present in a frame which is not the parent frame. If so, you've to switch to the frame before identifying the elements in it.

[Check out the link for more information](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3032)

Comment: If that's the case, selenium shouldn't be able to find elements even on the html surely? Anyway, I'm gonna check that if that's the case.

Comment: Fantastic thanks! Actually the proxy setting was the culprit all the while. Disabling it once and running the test suites worked for me. :) So this particular workaround was helpful: [Disable proxy](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3032#c13)

People should still continue to read into the mailing list link if this solution didn't work for them.

Answer (score 1):

protected mode settings in security tab should be same for all the four.
I also had same problem, its working now after I enabled protected mode for all the four zones.

Answer (score 0):

It's bit weird...but can you check by enabling the "**Compatibility mode**"

**Enable Compatibility Mode**

1) Tools->Compatibility view Settings

2) Check the Display all sites in compatibility view.

I hope it helps...all the best :-)

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I'm gonna try that out in a while.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help :( Still the same noSuchElementException on trying to find elements.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Internet explorer, behind a firewall, you might want to add in your security option, in local intranet, sites, advance setting, then, add your web adress.

For me it work